# How to make vertices z axis curved

Tags: three.js

I am working on three.js to create Terrain. How to make vertices z axis curved. When I assigned the geometry.vertices[i].position.z ='some value'. It raised the point and looks like triangle point. Please suggest.[image]

Comment: You need more points.

Comment: Could you explain little bit more ? Are you talking about points near to z axis?

Comment: First from what I see your x-y grid is 10x10 ? That is very low decimation so you dont have enough space to create a curved height. You need a more sophisticated data-structure than the one you are thinking. Take a look at http://vterrain.org/ and http://www.cognigraph.com/ROAM_homepage/ROAM2/ as a start.